# submit form via jquery, delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a form with few buttons

```
<form action="update" method="post" name="update-email">
        <input name="addr-0.ord" value="0" type="hidden" tabindex="3">

        <input name="addr-1.ord" value="1" type="hidden" tabindex="4">

        <input name="addr-2.ord" value="2" type="hidden" tabindex="5">

   <tr>
     <input type="submit" name="addr-0.delete" value="Delete" style="None" tabindex="8">
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <input type="submit" name="addr-1.delete" value="Delete" style="None" tabindex="10">
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <input type="submit" name="addr-2.delete" value="Delete" style="None" tabindex="12">
  </tr>

  </form>
```

How can I submit form with jquery.

```
$("update-email").submit()
```

This works if I use for edit button but not delete...
Any idea?

Comment: where is the button click event?

Comment: Your `style="None"` invalid! There is no element as `update-email`, and all your submit buttons will submit same form.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: you can use buttons in form and instead of click event of each buttons submit your form via jquery 

this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286384/php-submitting-a-form-with-multiple-submit-buttons-using-jquery-post) may be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use buttons in form and instead of click event of each buttons submit your form via jquery.

```
$("input[name="addr-0.delete"]").click(function(){

submitForm('addr-0.delete')

})

$("input[name="addr-1.delete"]").click(function(){

submitForm('addr-1.delete')

})

$("input[name="addr-2.delete"]").click(function(){

submitForm('addr-2.delete')

})

function submitForm(button){
  var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone ;
  dataString += '&button='+ button

$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "your_url",  
  data: dataStrings,  
  success: function() {  
    //success
  }  
});  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your button click event you can submit your form by its name.
try this:

```
$("form[name='update-email']").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one form and 3 submit button, the 3 buttons use the same action? I think the easiest way is make 3 form, with 3 differents actions, and the respective hidden input and submit button.

But, you can use simple buttons instead of submit button then attach event to all of it.

```
<tr>
    <form action="update-0" method="post" name="update-email-0">
        <input name="addr-0.ord" value="0" type="hidden" tabindex="3">
        <input type="submit" name="addr-0.delete" value="Delete" tabindex="8">
    </form>
</tr>
<tr>
    <form action="update-1" method="post" name="update-email-1">
        <input name="addr-1.ord" value="1" type="hidden" tabindex="4">
        <input type="submit" name="addr-1.delete" value="Delete" tabindex="10">
    </form>
</tr>
<tr>
    <form action="update-2" method="post" name="update-email-2">
        <input name="addr-2.ord" value="2" type="hidden" tabindex="5">
        <input type="submit" name="addr-2.delete" value="Delete" tabindex="12">
    </form>
</tr>

$("update-email-0").submit()
$("update-email-1").submit()
$("update-email-2").submit()
```

If you want to alter the submit event for any of this form you can do the next and make you custom submit from jquery:

```
$("form[name='update-email-0']").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $this.prop("action"),
        data: $this.serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function (data) {
        // Done here.
    });
});
```